# Load PHP and HTML code to a PHP variable echoed in a <div>

Tags: php, html, mixed-mode

Here is my case. I have the following script:

```
<?php
// ... other code ...
switch($_GET['request'])    {
        case "firstPage":
            $file = APP_ROOT. "pages/firstPage.php";
            $hndle = fopen($file,"r");
            $right_column = fread($hndle, filesize($file));
            fclose($hndle);
            break;
        case "secondPage":
            $file = APP_ROOT. "pages/secondPage.php";
            $hndle = fopen($file,"r");
            $right_column = fread($hndle, filesize($file));
            fclose($hndle);
            break;
    }
}
?>
<div id="right_column">
    <?php echo $right_column;?>
</div>
// ... other code ...
```

Depending on the value of the $_GET['request'] I am assigning to the variable $right_column the content of a php file. Then, I echo that variable in the last div. The firstPage.php and secondPage.php files contain mixed html and php code. I look for a solution like the 'partial' in Zend. Thanks

Comment: What is the problem here, what is the question?

Comment: @Chris: Sorry, tried to find a solution because my post had more than 250 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be simpler if you set a variable indicating which PHP file to include, and then rather than reading the file, just include it. For example:

```
<?php
// ... other code ...
switch($_GET['request'])    {
        case "firstPage":
            $file = APP_ROOT. "pages/firstPage.php";
            break;
        case "secondPage":
            $file = APP_ROOT. "pages/secondPage.php";
            break;
    }
}
?>
<div id="right_column">
    <?php include($file);?>
</div>
// ... other code ...
```

If your firstPage.php and secondPage.php files only had HTML, what you're doing would work. If it has PHP, then you'll need to `include()` it;  or you could `eval()` it but that is again doing more work than you need.

Comment: Thanks. Common sense, there is a huge backlog of questions with this subject, the solution was handy but amazingly, nobody saw it, including myself!

Answer (score 2):

First of all , your code is horrible, it should be something like :

```
$pages = array(
   'firstPage'   => 'pages/firstPage.php',
   'secondPage'  => 'pages/secondPage.php'
);

$request = 'firstPage';
if ( array_key_exits($_GET, 'request') 
 &&  array_key_exists($pages, $_GET['request']) )
{
   $request = $_GET['request'];
}
?>
<div id="right_column">
    <?php include  APP_ROOT . $pages[ $request ]; ?>
</div>
```

An please read http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html , you might find this interesting. It should explain to you , how you can easily take advantage of php's native templating capabilities.

Comment: your comment, in essence in line with the others above, reminds me of the early competitions to write the most unreadable C code possible. You have your point of view but I'm skeptical to reply on your 'horrible' attribute. ;-) though ...

Comment: @GingerOpariti , then try adding 12 different pages in your version .. and forget empty `request` parameter in url.

Comment: +1 This is definitely better than an ever expanding switch statement.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, reading and dumping your file is not a solution. You are just displaying code to your end-user.

What you need is parse the PHP file and display the result. You can do it in 2 ways:

First, intead of

```
 $file = APP_ROOT. "pages/firstPage.php";
 $hndle = fopen($file,"r");
 $right_column = fread($hndle, filesize($file));
 fclose($hndle);
```

You can do:

```
$right_column = include(APP_ROOT . "pages/firstPage.php");
```

So, your firstPage.php must RETURN the code. Something like this:

```
// firstPage.php
return "my html";
```

But you also can include it like this:

```
<div id="right_column">
    <?php include(APP_ROOT . "pages/firstPage.php"); ?>
</div>
```

Or, you can use the **ob_get_contents**. PHP has a [nice documentation](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) about how to use it.

I'd use include for your case.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that you could program by convention rather than have an ever increasing switch statement:

```
<?php
// ... other code ...

$file = '';
if (isset($_GET['request'])) {
    $safeFileName = sanitizeRequestForFileName($_GET['request']);
    $file = APP_ROOT. 'pages/' . $safeFileName . '.php';
}
?>
<div id="right_column">
    <?php 
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            include($file);
        }
    ?>
</div>
// ... other code ...
```

Comment: Are you sure that including a file just because it exists is the best idea ? There can be a lot of things inside `$_GET['request']`.

Comment: This is extremely insecure. What if `$_GET['request']` === `../uploads/hacker_script`? Oops.

Comment: @Chris that really isn't a reason to avoid programming by convention. You would simply write a method to sanitize the input, or use a store such as tereško's answer if you want to lock down the options. I just believe it is better if you don't need to change your code each time you want to add an extra option.